# C++: Name and linkage of what I'm doing?

Tags: c++, templates, linkage

Looking for the official name and the linkage type of this type of template specialization where we're specializing a template only to specialize the implementation of a single method within a class template.

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    void f() 
    {
        // default method implementation
    }
};

// What is the default linkage of this function (I'm guessing 
// external based on basic function template specializations), 
// and what am I doing called? (method specialization of a class 
// template?)
template <> 
void Foo<int>::f()
{
     // method implementation for Foo<int>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Foo<int> f1; f1.f(); //Use implementation for Foo<int>, i.e. the specialized one.
Foo<double> f2; f2.f(); //Use the default implementation.
```

The terminology behind this case is called Explicit Specialization. The compiler will select the "best" matching template it can find. The process to determine the "best" matching template is a little complicated. You may refer to the book "C++ Templates: The Complete Guide" for more details.

Comment: For the second question about linkage, however, do these explicit specializations get external linkage? Wasn't sure if I need to inline their implementations or put them into a separate compilation unit.